# WCF: Work with Entity Framework- App.config

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I have three project in a solution, let call them client, serivce and host respectively.

I follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 to build a service, which runs on a console host built by me, too.

I also use Entity Framework in service in order to store the data into MySql.

Now the question: Entity Framework has something realated with app.config in service project. However, the link above from Microsoft tells me to run the host as the start project, leading to the fact that service cannot find it's config, which is in service project instead of host project.

If I replace app.config in project host with app.config in project service, it throws some exception.

So what should I do to make my code work?

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- 部署服务库项目时，必须将配置文件的内容添加到
 主机的 app.config 文件中。System.Configuration 不支持库的配置文件。 -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server.CalculatorService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Server/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- 除非完全限定，否则地址相对于上面提供的基址-->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Server.ICalculator">
          <!-- 
              部署时，应删除或替换下列标识元素，以反映
             用来运行所部署服务的标识。删除之后，WCF 将
              自动推断相应标识。
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- 元数据交换终结点供相应的服务用于向客户端做自我介绍。 -->
        <!-- 此终结点不使用安全绑定，应在部署前确保其安全或将其删除-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- 为避免泄漏元数据信息，
          请在部署前将以下值设置为 false -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- 要接收故障异常详细信息以进行调试，
          请将以下值设置为 true。在部署前设置为 false 
          以避免泄漏异常信息 -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!--  <entityFramework>-->
  <!--    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">-->
  <!--      <parameters>-->
  <!--        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />-->
  <!--      </parameters>-->
  <!--    </defaultConnectionFactory>-->
  <!--    <providers>-->
  <!--      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
  <!--      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>-->
  <!--    </providers>-->
  <!--   -->
  <!--  </entityFramework>-->

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1Container" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=88;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=guessFigure" />
    <add name="RankADONETModel"
         connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=88;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=guessFigure"
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need also config the section like this under the "configuration",
change the sql provider to mysql

```
   <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```